# FindRoot with an Interpolation involving units

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, interpolation

Using Mathematica 10 I've defined two linear interpolating functions involving units: the first was written by my own and the second is the built in one.

What I need to do is using a simple FindRoot function but while the first one works well, the second does not. As an example I wrote a simple sample without any specific meaning, just for showing the problem.

I need to find a way for using the FindRoot function with the built-in Interpolation.

```
In[1]:= m = Quantity["Meters"];
In[2]:= kg = Quantity["Kilograms"];
In[3]:= linterp[x_, x0_, x1_, y0_, y1_] := (y0 + (y1 - y0)*(x - x0)/(x1 - x0));
In[4]:= kg1 = 2 kg; kg2 = 15 kg;
In[5]:= m1 = 3 m; m2 = 13 m;
In[6]:= f1[x_] := linterp[x, kg1, kg2, m1, m2]
In[7]:= f2[x_] := Interpolation[{{kg1, m1}, {kg2, m2}}, x, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
In[8]:= f1[7. kg]
Out[8]= Quantity[6.84615, "Meters"]
In[9]:= f2[7. kg]
Out[9]= Quantity[6.84615, "Meters"]

In[10]:= FindRoot[f1[x] == 6 m, {x, 1 kg}](*this works best*)
Out[10]= {x -> Quantity[5.9, "Kilograms"]}
In[11]:= FindRoot[f1[Quantity[x, "Kilograms"]] == 6 m, {x, 1}](*this works as well*)
Out[11]= {x -> 5.9}

In[12]:= FindRoot[f2[x] == 6 m, {x, 1 kg}](*does NOT work*)
Out[12]= {x -> Quantity[1., "Kilograms"]}
In[13]:= FindRoot[f2[Quantity[x, "Kilograms"]] == 6 m, {x, 1}](*does NOT work as well*)
Out[13]= {x -> 1.}
```

Comment: try defining `f3[x_/;NumericQ[x]]:=QuantityMagnitude[ f2[Quantity[x, "Kilograms"]]-6 m ]` and passing that to `FindRoot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take into account that Interpolation function works only in region specified by your data, in your example from 2 to 15, so you can't start with 1 in FindRoot.

I'm afraid it's not possible to use InterpolationFunction with units in FindRoot straightforwardly. But if you wish to keep all the units you always can do it this way (I agree.. it looks ugly):

```
f2 = Interpolation[{{kg1, m1}, {kg2, m2}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

num[x_] := QuantityMagnitude[x];  (* just shorter *)
(x /. FindRoot[num@f3[x kg] == num[6 m], {x, num[3 m]}]) QuantityUnit[f3[kg1]]
```

Also if you will work only with polynomial data then consider using InterpolatingPolynomial which seamlessly works with FindRoot (as it creates raw equation) just as your function linterp.